# jquery wrap isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an svg now ,i have to wrap each path inside an `<a>` tag but when i do using `.wrap()` in jQuery function every thing get hidden but when I inspect using fire bug the path tag get warped but every thing is hidden i tried to add display property but nothing works.

thanks

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @jycr   $("path").wrap("<a class='sadfa'></a>")

Comment: Since the documentation for wrap says it wraps with HTML content I guess it creates a HTML `<a>` element and wraps the path with that instead of an SVG `<a>` element. Check the namespace of the `<a>` element.

Comment: @RobertLongson  thanks it was a name space problem now it is working fine thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this was the namespace problem as suggested above by mr Robert Longson.

Svg anchor and html anchor both are different .As first when i was warping it using the .wrap function it was making the html anchor tag that is not visible inside the svg. because it doesn't understand it.

So for this i have first created the anchor tag with in the svg name space as shown below in to the code

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svgNS = svg.getAttribute('xmlns');
var a = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "a");
$("path").wrap(a);
```

As you can see

Thanks